# SwiftUI TabBar TabItems hidden when inactive in iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, swiftui

Starting with iOS 14.3, my TabBarItems are suddenly hidden, when it's not the active tab. It used to work with iOS 14.2 and works with every prior iOS Version. To be honest, I haven't tried it yet on a real device. This is my code:

```swift
struct MyTabView: View {
    
    @State var selectedIndex = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        // build the tabview and the tabs
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex) {

            MyView1()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "waveform.path.ecg")
            }.tag(0)
            
            MyView2()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            }.tag(1)
            
            ...
        }
        .accentColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea why this happens? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

[image: 13.0]
iOS 13.0
[image: 14.3]
iOS 14.3

Comment: Not reproducible with Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3. The issue may occur because of some other views.

Comment: The simulator is often very buggy. I would always test the code on a real device and use the simulator just for checking the layout and things like this.